# Symfony2 entity form field required multichoice

Tags: php, symfony

i have form in Symfony2. One of field is entity type:

```
->add('kind', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'TestBundle:Kind',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'required' => true
                    )
            )
```

I want extort thta user choose one of kind. But form allowed if user don't check anything. How  can I fix this ?

Comment: instead of entity make it a choice option

Comment: @david What more detailed ? This is my form field and i show form widget it;s all.

Comment: @plainjane if I change to choice nothing change

Comment: the `kind` entity has a relationship with another entity?

Answer (score 1):

Add [constraints](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#constraints) to this field in your `entity`. The `'required' => true` is just a client side validation, if you have an old browser, your form will always submit, because `HTML5 validations` only works on browsers that support `HTML5`

Answer (score 0):

The entity field works exactly in the same way than the "Select tag, Checkboxes or Radio Buttons".
This means you can use the same $options than the other type fields.

If you want to select just one kind from user with radio buttons use:

```
->add('kind', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'TestBundle:Kind',
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => false
                )
        )
```

Or if you want to select just one kind from user with a select tag use:

```
->add('kind', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'TestBundle:Kind',
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => false,
            'required' => true
                )
        )
```